# getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, list

```
arr = [1]
arr[0] = arr.pop()
```

giving me IndexError: list assignment index out of range
i don't understand why?

Comment: because you `pop`'d from the list, now the list has zero elements, then you try to assign to `arr[0]`, but since there *is not arr[0]*, you get the index error.

Answer (score 7):

By calling `arr.pop()` it makes `arr` change to `[]`, so after that if you try retrieving / chaging item at index `0` it will be out of range since its size is `0`

Answer (score 0):

The right-hand side of an assignment statement is evaluated before the left-hand side. So the list is empty when you try to assign at index 0.

You could rewrite your code roughly as:

```
arr = [1]
popped = arr.pop()
arr[0] = popped
```